# Is the elasticity of a submonoid of the free abelian monoid over a finite set either rational or infinite?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids, factorization-theory

Let $P$ be a finite set, $\mathscr F(P)$ the free abelian monoid with basis $P$, and $H$ a submonoid of $\mathscr F(P)$.

Given $x \in H \setminus \{1_H\}$, we let $\mathsf L_H(x)$ be the set of all $k \in \mathbf N^+$ such that $x = u_1 \cdots u_k$ for some atoms $u_1, \ldots, u_k \in H$, where $u \in H$ is an *atom* (or *irreducible element*) if $u \ne 1_H$ and $u \ne yz$ for all $y, z \in H \setminus \{1_H\}$.

It is relatively easy to show that $\mathsf L_H(x)$ is a non-empty finite subset of $\mathbf N^+$ for all $x \in H \setminus \{1_H\}$. Accordingly, we define the *elasticity* of $H$ by 
$$
\rho(H) := \sup \{\max \mathsf L_H(x)/\min \mathsf L_H(x): x \in H\} \in [1,\infty],
$$
with the convention that $\mathsf L_H(1_H) := \{0\} \subseteq \mathbf N$ and $\frac{0}{0} := 1$. Here comes my first question:

> **Q1.** Is it true that either $\rho(H) = \infty$ or $\rho(H) \in \mathbf Q$?

My feeling is that the conclusion should not be true in this generality, but I'd like to see a counterexample. On the other hand, I don't have a feeling about the following variant, which is much closer to the case in which I'm most interested:

> **Q2.** Assume $H$ is *simple*, that is, $E_P(H) \cap {\rm supp}_P(x) \ne \emptyset$ for all $x \in H \setminus \{1_H\}$, where $$E_P(H) := \{p \in P: p^k \in H \text{ for some }k \in \mathbf N^+\}\subseteq P$$ and $${\rm supp}_P(x) := \{p \in P: p \mid_{\mathscr F(P)} x\}\subseteq P.$$ Is it true that either $\rho(H) = \infty$ or $\rho(H)$ is rational?

For instance, the answer to Q1 is yes if:

1. $H$ is half-factorial, i.e., $\mathsf L_H(x)$ is a singleton for
   all $x \in H$ (this is obvious);
2. $H$ is finitely generated (more
   in general, it follows from a non-trivial application of [Dickson's
   lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_lemma) that every cancellative, commutative monoid $M$ such that
   the quotient $M/M^\times$ is finitely generated, has rational
   elasticity);
3. $H$ is a simple C-monoid (this is highly non-trivial), where $H$ is called a C-monoid if there exists $\alpha \in \mathbf N^+$ such that $H \cap p^{2\alpha} \mathscr F(P) = p^\alpha(H \cap p^\alpha \mathscr F(P))$ for all $p \in P$;
4. $P = \{p,q\}$ is a $2$-element set and $H = \{p^x q^y: y < \alpha x\}$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbf R^+$ (it is a nice exercise to show that, in this case, the elasticity is always infinite).